# Is there a wsadmin command to insert an arbitrary line of text into WebSphere's trace.log and SystemOut.log?

Tags: bash, shell, debugging, websphere

I have some processes (in a Bash shell) external to WAS that interact with a WAS portlet over a Web Services interface. I'm trying to find a way to programmatically insert from Bash a line like "BGN Debugging here" into trace.log and SystemOut.log. I thought there would be a way using wsadmin, but my Google-fu fails me, and browsing the commands for the wsadmin objects didn't turn up any command that seemed promising. Is there such a command, or is there another way to essentially perform printf debugging in these log files?

TL;DR (for mona): What do I call from a Bash Shell to programmatically insert a string into the trace.log and SystemOut.log WebSphere files?

Comment: Hi pal ! do we need some editing with this one? Ore is it only me who didn't understand what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

One low-rent solution is to install a simple debugging application, or even JSP in an existing application. that only accepts request from localhost and writes to SystemOut.  This would be considerably more lightweight then e.g. wsadmin or jmx.

Comment: Or hit http://localhost:9080/debug/session/001, which will leave an entry like this in the log: WebContainer  E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.internal.WebContainer handleRequest SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /debug/session/001 has not been defined.